# Why we have not eliminated hurricanes and tornadoes?

Tags: weather

Hurricanes are caused by too much warm humidity in the air. When this humid air encounters cold air, the humidity condenses to water which forms a low pressure region of air. The low pressure region will suck surrounding air in and form an even bigger low pressure region, so a hurricane is formed. So if we lower the air humidity before forming a hurricane, we can eliminate a hurricane or a tornado. Lowing the air humidity can also alter a hurricane route or weaken it.
Why we have not done it?

Comment: "... by artificial precipitations ..." this is the activity colloquially known as rain-making. It has been attempted by a number of methods but as far as I know with no large-scale success yet.

Comment: Hurricanes involve huge amounts of energy moving around (out of the tropics to cooler places). I suppose if one set up huge heat pumps to move all that energy around, but the total energy to be moved is left as an exercise...

Comment: There were successful cloud seeding cases. https://stillunfold.com/science/7-most-popular-cases-of-cloud-seeding  We only need to use small amount of energy to trigger the natural process.

Comment: The trick is that the rain has to fall somewhere other than where all that cloud moisture is generated - there is a reason those clouds form - there is a lot of moisture in the air because of how warm the ocean and air in the tropics are.

Comment: No. Making clouds is enough to reduce a hurricane. Because clouds is no longer a gas but liquid. Only gas changing to liquid will form low air  pressure which could form a hurricane.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article on [Project Stormfury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Stormfury), a U.S. government attempt to do this between 1962 and 1983, “Most hurricanes do not contain enough supercooled water for cloud seeding to be effective.”

Comment: Good. A hurricane will be difficult to start with. I am not surprised to see some failures. But tornados would be a good start place.

Comment: Project Stormfury is very interesting. They tried to destroy existing hurricanes. When they were done right, they get a few successful cases. I think their budget was too small. I would expect to cost more than $100 millions and use thousands people to eliminate a hurricane. My approach is different: to deplete the fuel of a hurricane by cloud seeding making rain storms before a hurricane formation.

Comment: By observing hurricane Dorian, I noticed when Dorian moved through a region where there was no rain storms a few days before, it changed from Category 3 to 4 and 5. When Dorian moved through a region where had rain storms a day before, it changed from Category 3 to 2 and 1. Of course there are other factors affect a hurricane intensity. But rain storms will deplete a hurricane's fuel.

Answer (score 1):

> So if we lower the air humidity before forming a hurricane by artificial precipitations, we can eliminate a hurricane or a tornado. Lowing the air humidity can also alter a hurricane route or weaken it. Why we have not done it?

I am not sure why this question has been downvoted so much. It is a valid question, we can remove humidity in a home, why not for a hurricane?

The reason is simply a question of scale. Hurricanes form when temperatures are above 80 F (300 K) and when the air is very humid, let's say 90% RH (relative humidity). I don't know what it would take to eliminate a hurricane, but just to do an order of magnitude estimate let's say that to weaken it sufficiently we would need to reduce the humidity from 90% to 75%. That 15% decrease in humidity corresponds to only 4 mg/L (mg of water vapor per L of air).

That 75% RH is a dew point of 71 F (295 K), so that means that we need to cool a surface to 295 K, and pump the heat generated by the condensation of water out to the ambient 300 K. If we assume an ideal (Carnot) heat pump then the COP for cooling is 59, meaning that it takes 1 J of work to move 59 J of heat between those temperatures. The latent heat of evaporation is 2256 kJ/kg. So we have 2256 mJ/mg * 4 mg/L /59 = 150 mJ/L.

150 mJ/L doesn't seem like such a huge amount, and in fact if you are dehumidifying a building it is not such a problem. But the problem is that hurricanes are enormous. Let's say that you don't need to get the entire storm, but just the central portion out to 50 km radius, and let's say that you only need to dry out the bottom 1 km of air. That is 7850 km^3 which works out to 7.85 PL. That works out to about 1 PJ of energy. That is roughly the total annual energy consumption of a country like Greenland.

We would need use a mobile platform to bring that much energy all at once to a place in the middle of the ocean without any losses, put it through our ideal heat engine, and move the humid air through the device without using any additional energy. And that is assuming that 15% reduction over the volume indicated is sufficient.

Comment: excellent exposition!

Comment: I do not disagree your calculation. But we do not need to produce that much cold. Just like the formation of a hurricane, we only need to cool small amount of air to form an air low pressure which will cuck in sounding air including cold air from higher altitude. The same process to trigger a formation of a hurricane or a tornado to start precipitation.

Comment: “we do not need to produce that much cold. Just like the formation of a hurricane, we only need to cool small amount of air to form an air low pressure which will cuck in sounding air including cold air from higher altitude” I don’t think there is any scientific basis for this claim, but I am glad to be corrected if you have a reputable scientific reference to support it.

Comment: Cloud seeding is a mature technique. https://stillunfold.com/science/7-most-popular-cases-of-cloud-seeding How could you not to know it?

Comment: Cloud seeding doesn’t work for hurricanes and tornadoes because the air is not supersaturated. Only thermodynamic techniques will work to reduce the humidity of a non-supersaturated water vapor.

Comment: The purpose of cloud seeding is to make air supersaturated. You do not think that cloud seeding is a thermodynamic process?

Comment: That is not the purpose of cloud seeding. Cloud seeding provides nucleation sites so that droplets can form in supersaturated air. It neither reduces the temperature nor increases the humidity, so it does not create supersaturated air. You misunderstand cloud seeding and also seem to not recognize how weak the evidence supporting it is. This is not a feasible way for large scale reliable weather control.

Comment: That is what your understanding. The fact is that cloud seeding will trigger precipitation.  It has been proven.

Comment: It is not only my understanding. https://www.nap.edu/catalog/10829/critical-issues-in-weather-modification-research At this point the moderators are reminding me that comments are not for extended discussion, so I’m done. You’re free to believe in the effectiveness of cloud seeding, and be surprised that we still allow hurricanes to form. Or you can take the obvious fact that we allow them to form as another indication that it doesn’t work. If simply dropping particles in clouds could reliably stop hurricanes then we would certainly do it. The choice of a rational or irrational belief is yours